# How to emulate keyboard events with javascript (or not javascript) in webview (android) to type in textarea

Tags: javascript, android, html, textarea, android-webview

I try to emulate typing in `textarea` in `html`, that is located in `webview` (android), but all solutions i've tried do not work. Solutions like `textarea.value = "value` do not pass to me. Could anybody advise something? 
It should be the same as for html-page without webview and android.

I've spent a lot of time so thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Why doesn't `textarea.value = "value"` pass to you?

Comment: You can use the [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) API to send key events to your own Activities. Specfically `.sendKeyDownUpSync(int keycode)` is the method you want. If you are looking to send key events to activities that are not your own, then it is not possible on a stock device using the public APIs, the ability to do so would represent a serious security flaw with the system.

Comment: There is some script in the page that clears the textarea if i try to do textarea.value = "value".

Comment: The issue is that i write a UI tests for one application. Everything is written with the using of robotium and we used javascript to emulate events for webviews. But here i should emulate keyboard-events and it fails. I can't use Android api as it's not android controls but html.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very Sure but did you try to make the reference of the textArea and then manipulating it for eg:

```
var ref= document.getElementById("txtArea"); 
ref.InnerHTML="hello";
```

Please select this as the best answer if you find it helpful.